# How to write groovy script in jenkins pipeline for Powershell command

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I want to run parallel jobs in jenkins using the pipeline groovy scripts for Powershell command.

I have tried putting the powershell command inside Bat and and powershell inside groovy script but its failing.

## Copy to Dev CM Server

```
NET USE \\10.207.24.148\IPC$ /u:nextgen-dev-cm01\Administrator Complete!123
robocopy  d:\nextGenBuild\Dev \\10.207.24.148\d$\wwwroot\cm01.dev.amgen-test.com\ /e 
NET USE \\10.206.24.147\IPC$ /D
```

## Copy to Dev CD Server

```
NET USE \\10.207.24.178\IPC$ /u:nextgen-dev-cd01\Administrator Complete!123
robocopy  d:\nextGenBuild\Dev \\10.207.24.178\d$\wwwroot\cd01.dev.amgen-test.com\ /e 
NET USE \\10.207.24.178\IPC$ /D
```

I want two scrips for CM server and CD server  to be run parallely.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your post and add the groovy script you have tried, and what error you are getting.

Comment: @Abinash, your scripts are plain bat. So, just use pipeline `bat`